Dative in front of accusative
Duolingo tells me that I can't say

Carlos macht ein Picknick mit seinen Freunden.

It says I have to put "mit seinen Freunden" in front of "ein Picknick":

Carlos macht mit seinen Freunden ein Picknick.

Is there a specific rule which says that  dative must be in front of accusative?

The phrase "mit seinen Freunden" actually isn't dative but a prepositional phrase with a preposition that requires dative. A sentence like "Ich gab ihm ein Buch" has a true dative, "ihm". That should come before the accusative; the other way is wrong: *"Ich gab ein Buch ihm."

Both versions are completely fine:

Carlos macht mit seinen Freunden ein Picknick.


Carlos macht ein Picknick mit seinen Freunden.

In general, the word order in German is relatively flexible. One of the few rules that need to be adhered to in almost all cases is that the verb is in second position ("macht" in this case). Other than that, there's a kind of "usual" word order with a neutral undertone. Changes to that word order can be used to put emphasis on a part of the sentence.
In this example, I'd consider

Carlos macht mit seinen Freunden ein Picknick.

as the "usual", more neutral word order. In

Carlos macht ein Picknick mit seinen Freunden.

there is a slight emphasis on "mit seinen Freunden".
When Duolingo doesn't accept a sentence, it doesn't necessarily mean that the sentence is wrong. To the best of my knowledge, the app has an internal list of correct answers for each exercise, and the version you answered with may just not be on the list yet.

If you want to emphasize strongly, you could even say "Nur mit seinen Freunden macht Carlos ein Picknick, nie mit seinen Feinden!" Interestingly, the verb is still in second position; the subject is relegated to third.

That's funny, I'd consider the second option, "Carlos macht ein Picknick mit seinen Freunden.", to be the "usual" order. Maybe it's a local thing?

@Sabine As I mentioned, it's only a slight emphasis, so it might well come down to individual preference.

Duolingo is wrong. Both versions are correct and perfectly fine. German has much more flexibility in its word order than many other languages like English. The inflected part of the verb must be at position 2 of a main clause, all other parts of the verb at the very end (sometimes with exceptions). The subject is on position 1 or 3 (in a main clause). Anything else is more or less up to the speakers or authors mood.
These are perfectly fine versions of your sentence:

Carlos macht mit seinen Freunden ein Picknick.
Carlos macht ein Picknick mit seinen Freunden.
Mit seinen Freunden macht Carlos ein Picknick.
Ein Picknick macht Carlos mit seinen Freunden.

Versions 1 is the standard version but version 2 is almost equally fine. The other versions are grammatically correct, but are only used if you want to emphasize »mit deinen Freunden« (in Version 3) or »ein Picknick« (in version 4).

By the way (Is it really dative?):
The part »mit seinen Freunden« is NOT a dative object! It is neither in dative case nor is it an object. It is an adverbial (name in German grammar: »adverbiale Bestimmung«) in no grammatical case at all.
Why is it not an object?
Because the verb does not demand it. You can build a sentence without this part and it would be perfectly fine, or you could use some other prepositional phrase with another preposition and it would also be fine:

no prepositional phrase

Carlos macht ein Picknick.


another prepositional phrase (with another preposition)

Carlos macht ein Picknick auf der Wiese.
Carlos macht ein Picknick am späten Abend.



But »mit seinen Freunden« is with no doubt a prepositional phrase (a phrase that starts with a preposition). If it's a prepositional phrase but not an object, then it is an addition of the verb, so it's part of the sentence's predicate. (Objects do not belong to the predicate in German.) And this makes it an »adverbiale Bestimmung«.
There are verbs that demand a prepositional phrase as one of its objects:
The verb »bestehen« (to consist of, to be made of) wants a prepositional object with the preposition »aus«:

Milchflaschen bestehen aus Glas.

You can't omit the object »aus Glas« and you can't replace it with a prepositional phrase with another preposition.

wrong: Milchflaschen bestehen.
wrong: Milchflaschen bestehen am späten Abend.

Note, there is also the verb »bestehen« with the meaning »to exist« or »to resist« and another verb »bestehen« with the meaning »to pass (a test)« which doesn't need a prepositional object. But these are homonyms. If you want the meaning »to consist«, you need a mandatory prepositional object.
Why is it in no grammatical case at all? Isn't it in dative case?
This is even more puzzling, isn't it?
Well, there is a dative case inside the prepositional phrase »mit seinen Freunden«. The nominal group »seinen Freunden« indeed is in dative case. But the case of this nominal group does not depend on anything outside of this prepositional phrase. It is encapsulated inside the prepositional phrase, and the case of »seinen Freunden« does not interact with anything outside the prepositional phrase. Its case depends only on the preposition.
But the whole prepositional phrase (preposition + inner nominal group) has no grammatical case at all, and you can't separate the preposition from its inner nominal group. These two components (1: preposition; 2: inner nominal group or sometimes a pronoun) build one solid block that can be moved to other places in the sentence, but the words »mit seinen Freunden« always stick together. And this block has no grammatical case.

The king of every sentence is the full verb. If it is the only verb in the sentence, then its throne is at position 2. Otherwise (if there is an auxiliary verb or a modal verb in addition to the full verb) its throne is the very end of the main clause. This verb rules over its subject, its adverbials and its objects.
German has these types of objects (which are ruled by the full verb):

accusative objects

Ich sehe meinen Vater.


dative objects

Walter ähnelt meinem Vater.


genitive objects

Die Trauergemeinde gedenkt meines Vaters.


prepositional objects (in no case at all!)

with inner nominal phrase in accusative case

Markus beschwert sich über meinen Vater.


with inner nominal phrase in dative case

Das Buch handelt von meinem Vater.





Prepositional phrases can be objects in which case they depend on the verb as just shown. But they can also be independent from the verb. If this is the case, you can replace them with prepositional phrases that have another preposition, as shown in these examples:

Adverbial (adverbiale Bestimmung) (not an object and in no grammatical case at all!)

with inner nominal phrase in accusative case

Laura geht ohne meinen Vater zu meiner Mutter.


with inner nominal phrase in dative case

Laura geht mit meinem Vater zu meiner Mutter.


with inner nominal phrase in genitive case

Laura geht wegen meines Vaters zu meiner Mutter.





Note, that »zu meiner Mutter« is also an »adverbiale Bestimmung« in the examples above. This is another hint that it's not a prepositional object. Each verb can have only at most one prepositional object. But there can be as many adverbials as you want:

Laura geht trotz des schlechten Wetters mit ihrer Freundin am späten Abend durch den Wald zu meiner Mutter.

These are all »adverbiale Bestimmungen«. The verb does not demand any of them:

trotz des schlechten Wetters
mit ihrer Freundin
am späten Abend
durch den Wald
zu meiner Mutter


Das Römische Imperium bestand über mehrere Jahrhunderte.

@bakunin: I already mentioned, that there are also homonyms of bestehen that to not mean to consist which do not need a prepositional object, and of course they can have adverbiale Bestimmungen with variable prepositions. (Dreimal adverbiale Bestimmung: 1. »Das Römische Imperium bestand wegen seiner inneren Stärke.« 2. »Das R.I. bestand bereits vor Christi Geburt.« 3. »Das R.I. bestand rund um das Mittelmeer.« ABER: Ein anderes Verb (ein Homonym) und ein fixes Präpositionalobjekt, das jetzt vom Verb verlangt wird: »Das Römische Imperium bestand aus mehreren Provinzen.«)

You mentioned these homonyms, but "bestehen aus", "bestehen in", "bestehen während", etc., are not homonyms but the exact same word: the verb basically meaning "to be/to exist"). This - that they are NOT homonyms but still use different prepositions - was my point.

@bakunin: »bestehen aus« = to be made of; to consist of: »Die Flasche besteht aus Glas. Das Puzzle besteht aus 512 Teilen.« This does NOT mean to exist! If you mean to be made of or to consist of, then you need a mandatory prepositional object and this object must be »aus«! When »bestehen« is not used in this meaning, but in the meaning to be, to exist, then you don't need a prepositional object. But you can use other prepositional groups but they are not objects! They are part of the predicate and can have any preposition. That is what defines them as »adverbiale Bestimmung«

This is a great answer, I don't understand why it's being downvoted.

@gented Maybe the answer is considered too long/sophisticated/detailed for the person who asked the question in the first place? (this person being apparently a beginner with the German language)

@SylvainGadenne: I don't care about downvoting, and I don't care about the skills of the people who write the questions. Maybe you are right about my answer being to long/sophisticated/detailed for the person who asked the question in the first place. But this single person is not the only one who will read this answer. Some answers are read by thousands of different people, and many of them are more experienced, and I want them to learn something too.

Dies ist bei Weitem die beste Antwort (obgleich die anderen auch gut sind). Als Deutschlerner mit etwas Erfahrung hat sie mir auch neues Wissen beigebracht. Danke!

@S.G. Du ahnst gar nicht, wie sehr es mich freut zu lesen, dass ich als autodidaktischer Deutsch-Laie einem Deutschlehrer was beibringen konnte! (Ich unterrichte Statistik und theoretische Informatik an einer Hochschule an Österreich, bei der ich als Forscher auf dem Gebiet der IT-Sicherheit beschäftigt bin. Derzeit arbeite ich gerade an einem Quantenkryptografie-Projekt. In der Schule  (Matura 1983) hatte ich nicht nur einen extrem miserablen Deutschlehrer sondern auch immer sehr schlechte Noten in allen Sprachen (Deutsch, Englisch, Latein).)

You could mention that the grammatical case of the noun in the adverbial simply depends on the requirement of the preposition: "Er macht ein Picknick mit seinen* Freunden* und für seine* Freunde*."

Der "autodidaktische Deutsch-Laie" hat hier Deutschlerner als Deutschlehrer gelesen. Ich lehre zwar nix, aber ich stelle - nämlich richtig! ;-)

The rule as it's usually taught is:

Pronouns precede nouns,
Dative nouns precede accusative nouns.
Accusative pronouns precede dative pronouns.

But when a noun occurs with a preposition like "mit", these rules don't apply. The proposition+noun combination acts more like an adverb, and is sometimes called an adverbial phrase. Adverbs and adverbial phrases are not nouns and aren't subject to the three rules given above; even if they do contain a noun, their behavior in a sentence is different from a noun.
That being said, the rules given above are really more guidelines in practice. German word order is flexible, and German uses inflection instead of word order to determine the role each element of a sentence plays. That doesn't mean German word order is completely random, but it is more flexible than English. This flexibility allows you to use word order as a way of giving emphasis to certain words, but doing this idiomatically is difficult for beginners and so it's usually best to stay with the "default" order, following the above rules, if you're still learning.
